# Details on Proving that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M f(x) \cos (nx) dx=0$ Using Density of Step Functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

I was working on a question very similar to this post: [Show that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi ~f(x) \cos (nx) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)$ converges to $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85944/show-that-int-pi-pi-fx-cos-nx-mathrmd-mux-converges-to-0) .

I want to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M  f(x) \cos (nx) dx=0$ for a closed and bounded interval $[-M,M]$ provided $f\in L^1([-M,M])$. The answer to the link above says that for any step function $g$ in $[-M,M]$, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M  g(x) \cos (nx) dx=0.$$

I want to supply the details that will prove that the limit of the original integral will vanish. Since, step functions in $[-M,M]$ are dense in $L^1([-M,M])$, then there exists a sequence $(g_m)$ if step functions in $[-M,M]$ that converges to $f$ in the $L^1([-M,M])$ norm. We also know that up to a subsequence $(g_{m_{k}})$, it also converges pointwise a.e. to $f$. Therefore, since $$|g_{m_k}cos(nx)|\leq|g_{m_k}|,$$ and $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M|g_{m_k}|=\int_{-M}^M|f|,$$ then by the Generalized Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem (we can 'pass the limit'): $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M  f(x) \cos (nx) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_{m_k}(x) \cos (nx) dx $$ $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M  f(x) \cos (nx) dx = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{-M}^M g_{m_k}(x) \cos (nx) dx=0.$$ This proves the theorem. Is my proof correct?

Comment: No need to invoke the dominated convergence theorem. Please have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Proof

Comment: So I can use a similar proof using approximation by step function and limsup?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

By the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma we know that if $f\in L^1$ then $$\lim_{|n|\to\infty} \hat{f}(n)=0$$
    this is to say that $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{in x} dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\cos nx dx+i\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\sin nx dx$$ therefore$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\cos nx dx=0\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;
 \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\sin nx dx=0
 $$

Comment: I just read that you wanted to use density of simple functions,  :(

Comment: The problem is suitable for Fejer's Lemma. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) is a proof that building up from simple functions and then using the density of step functions.

Answer (score 0):

This may be seen as a particular case of Féjer's Lemma:

> Fejér's formula:
> Suppose $g$ is a bounded measurable $T$-periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ ($T>0$). For any integrable function $f$ (denoted by $f\in\mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R})$) and numeric sequence $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$,
> $$
> \lim_n\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)g(nx+a_n)\,dx=\Big(\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0 g\Big)\int_\mathbb{R} f \tag{1}\label{one}
> $$

A proof based on the density of step functions in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ can be found in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671)