# Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E \cos^2(nx + a_n) dx = \frac{1}{2}m(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

My task is basically to show that if $E$ is any measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$, $m(E) < \infty$ and $\{a_n\}$ is any sequence of real numbers then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E \cos^2(nx + a_n) dx = \frac{1}{2}m(E)$

Usually for such limits, my class has relied on the use of theorems such as monotone or dominated convergence, but the issue here is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos^2(nx + a_n)$ does not converge. Does anyone have any hints for getting started?

Comment: You could try starting with $a_n=0$, and then using $\cos$ addition formula to generalize the result

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: I wish I knew. This was just a question on a problem set given by my professor, but I have no idea how/where he obtains his questions

Comment: What is $E$ precisely ?

Comment: Oh sorry! I'll edit my question - $E$ is just any measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Are you allowed to use Riemann-Lebesgue lemma? In such case, the proof is rather straightforward.

Comment: Yes I think I am, we just started covering it

Comment: As suggested in Yves Daoust's answer, use double-angle formula to expand the cosine square and then you can apply Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos^2(nx+a_n)=\frac12+\frac12\cos(2nx+2a_n),$$ and the first term yields the desired RHS.

The other term makes a vanishing integral as the cosine cancels out on whole periods, and the contribution of the incomplete intervals is of order $O(n^{-1})$.

Comment: If $E$ is not a finite union of bounded intervals, the vanishing speed can be actually slower than $\frac{1}{n}$. We may rather invoke Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for that part.

Comment: @SangchulLee: right. When I answered, $E$ was not defined.

Answer (score 4):

This is to expand the result of the OP using the the comment of Sangchul Lee.
We consider
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_E\cos^{2m}(n x+ \alpha_n)\,dx\tag{0}\label{zero}\end{align}$$
where $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha_n$ is an arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

From $\cos\theta=2^{-1}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$, we obtain that
$$\begin{align}
\cos^{2m}(\theta)&=2^{-2m}\sum^{2m}_{k=0}\binom{2m}{k}e^{i\theta (2m-2k)}\\
&=2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}+2^{-2m}\Big(\sum^{m-1}_{k=0}\binom{2m}{k}e^{i\theta (2m-2k)}+\sum^{2m}_{k=m+1}\binom{2m}{k}e^{i\theta (2m-2k)}\Big)\\
&=2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}+2^{-2m+1}\sum^m_{k=1}\binom{2m}{m-k}\cos(2k\theta)
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$
\int_E\cos^{2m}(nx+\alpha_n)\,dx=2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}\lambda(E)+2^{-2m+1}\sum^m_{k=1}\binom{2m}{m-k}\int_E\cos(2k(nx+\alpha_n))\,dx$$

By Riemann-Lebesgue's lemma,
$$\Big|\int_E\cos(2knx+2k\alpha_n)\,dx\Big|\leq\Big|\int_E\cos(2knx)\,dx\Big|+\Big|\int_E\sin(2knx)\,dx\Big|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

Putting things together, we obtain the more general formula

$$\lim_n\int_E\cos^{2m}(nx+\alpha_n)\,dx=2^{-2m}\binom{2m}{m}\lambda(E)$$

The OP for example, corresponds to $m=1$.

---

One last interesting thing. The limit in \eqref{zero} can also be approached by [Fejer's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) which states that if $\phi\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is a bounded $T$-periodic measurable function, then
$$\lim_n\int \phi(x) f(nx+\alpha_n)\,dx = \Big(\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f\Big)\Big(\int \phi\Big)$$
for any sequence $\mathbb{\alpha_n}$. Letting $\phi(x)=\mathbb{1}_E$, and $f(x)=\cos^{2p}(x)$, we have that $f$ is $\pi$--periodic and so
$$\lim_n\int_E\cos^{2m}(nx+\alpha_n)\,dx =\lambda(E)\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0\cos^{2m}(x)\,dx$$

The formula we obtained before gives us the estimate $\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0\cos^{2m}(x)\,dx=2^{-2m+1}\binom{2m}{m}$.