# Prove $F_n(x) = \int_0^x f(\sin(nt))dt$ where $f$ is Riemann integrable converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I just took my real analysis qualifying exam yesterday and this problem showed up:

Prove $F_n(x) = \int_0^x f(\sin(nt))dt$ where $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $[0,\infty)$ and find its limit.

There were two previous parts to the problem, showing that $F_n$ is uniformly Lipschitz and that on every compact set of $\mathbb{R}$ $F_n$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence. I believe I proved those two parts correctly but I had no idea how to do this last part.

Comment: I think convergence is uniform in compact subsets of $[0,\infty)$ only since $F_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}x\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 f\circ\sin$. The limit can be found using this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671)

Comment: What is the argument as for why it converges to $x\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f\circ\sin$?

Comment: Hmmm measure theory was not on the quals syllabus and therefore we were not allowed to use it.

Comment: The actual full question was to show that it converged uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ but they said they would give full credit for showing it on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: No, I said I proved that on any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ it has a uniformly convergent subsequence. The third part was to prove the entire sequence converged uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- $f\circ\sin $ is $2\pi$-periodic, and the integrability of $f$ over $[-1,1]$ implies that $f\circ \sin$ is in integrable over $[0,2\pi]$.
- The rest is based on this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068640/integration-of-a-periodic-function/3741777#3741777): The change of variables $u=n\,t$ and the $2\pi$-periodicity of $f\circ\sin $ gives
  $$
  \begin{align}
  F_n(x)&=\frac{1}{n}\int^{nx}_0 f\circ\sin (u)\,du=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{[nx/2\pi]}_{k=1}\int^{2\pi k}_{2\pi(k-1)}f\circ \sin +\frac{1}{n}\int^{nx}_{2\pi[nx/2\pi]}f\circ\sin\\
  &=\frac{1}{n}\Big[\frac{nx}{2\pi}\Big]\int^{2\pi}_0f\circ\sin + \frac{1}{n}\int^{nx}_{2\pi[nx/2\pi]}f\circ\sin
  \end{align}
  $$
  The term $E_n=\int^{nx}_{2\pi[nx/2\pi]}f\circ\sin$ is bounded:
  $|E_n|\leq 2\pi \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in[-1,1]\}$ independently of $x$. Hence
  $\lim_nF_n(x)=x\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 f\circ\sin$.

---

With a little extra effort one can tweak the arguments above and show that convergence is indeed uniform in compacts sets of $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps one would then use this result to prove it converges uniformly on [0,infty). I'll give it a try.