# Convergence of a sequence in $(C[0,1])^*$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I would like to determine if the following sequence of linear functionals on $C[0,1]$ converges weakly (i.e. pointwise) and strongly (with respect to the norm) $$ \phi_n(f)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}(nt^2-[nt^2])f(t)dt,$$ where $[x]$ means greatest integer that is less than or equal to $x$. I do not know how to investigate this question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: Draw a graph of $nt^2 -[nt^2]$ for large $n$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz what does $\implies$ mean?

Comment: @OliverDiaz I'm grinding through a simple computation at the moment, I am not convinced of the $\{ nx^2\}$ case yet. I would expect some 'area multiplier' at minimum.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I should do some paying work too :-).

Comment: @OliverDiaz Looks good, I was expecting some constant (the ${ 1\over 2}$ below), I am still (slowly) trying to compute it for $f=1$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Not surprisingly (given your answer) $\int\limits_{0}^{1} \{nt^2\} dt \to {1 \over 2}$, but off the bat it was not what I thought.

Comment: Pointwise convergence is weak-star convergence, which matters here.

Comment: @TimurB. I ignore if whether there is simpler solution, but when the measures in $[0,1]$ or any other finite interval $[0,T]$ for that matter, you have measures of the form $\mu_n(dx)=f(nx+b_n)\,dx$ where $f$ defined on $[0,T]$, one may try to extend $f$  the whole real line as periodic functions. The result by Féjer can then applied to suitable test functions ($\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ in your case).

Comment: This is a perfectly good question with an insightful answer. I really do not get this rush to close & delete. there are plenty of rubbish, truly low quality questions, sure they should be dealt with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $h(t)=\{t\}=t-[t]$ is $1$-periodic. The change of variable $u=t^2$ gives
$$\int^1_0f(t)\{nt^2\}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 \frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u}}\,h(nu)\,du$$

Notice that  $g(u)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(u)\frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u}}$ is integrable for any $f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])$.  By [Féjer's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671),
$$\begin{align}
\frac12\int^1_0 \frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u}}h(nu)\,du&= \frac12\int_\mathbb{R}g(u)\,h(n\,u)\,du\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac12\Big(\int^1_0 h(u)\,du\Big)\int_\mathbb{R}g(u)\,du\\
&=\frac14\int^1_0 \frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u}}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0f
\end{align}$$
Therefore, the sequence of measures $\phi_n(dt)=\{nt^2\}\,dt$ converge to $\frac{1}{2}dx$ in $(\mathcal{C}[0,1])^*$ with the weak-* topology.

Comment: Never seen this formula caller Fejer's.  Do you have a reference? (No critic, just curious)

Comment: @daw: I learnt of that result in a book of problems by Claude, George , Exercices et Problèms d'integration, BORDAS, Paris, 1980 who attributed to Féjer. Other versions (without attribution) and some restriction have been discussed in MSE, but the version I have applies for any bounded measurable $T$-peridoc function $h$ and any integrable function $g$. It is a beautiful result, in fact Riemann-Lebesgue's theorem, at least in $L_2(\mathbb{T}$, can be deduced from it.