# extension of Riemann lemma

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, lebesgue-integral

if$f,g\mathpunct{:}\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$satisfy$f,g,fg\in L^1$,and$\exists T(g(x+T)=g(x))$,Is the following equation valid?
$$
\lim_{ n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)g(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x =\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}g(x)  \, \mathrm{d}x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x 
$$
The teacher at school taught us the proof when g is bounded. I don't know how to handle general situations

Comment: Why not include the proof of the bounded case in your question?

Comment: The bounded case us [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068640/integration-of-a-periodic-function). For unbounded, this holds for $L_p$, $p>1$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674103/121671)

Comment: The assumption on $g$ is not quite correct Since it $g$ is  $T$-periodic ($T>0$), $g\in L_1(
\mathbb{R})$ would yield $g=0$ a.s. The assumption should be $g\in L_1[0,T]$ instead.