# Convergence of series $\sum_n|b_n g(nx+a_n)|$ in a set of positive measure implies convergence of $\sum_n|b_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

This problem is in a set of old past qualifying tests I am using for practice.

Suppose $g$ is bounded measurable function of period $T$ with $m(x:|f(x)|>0)>0$. Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ numerical sequences and suppose that $G(x)=\sum_n|b_n g(nx+a_n)|$ converges for all points $x$ in a set of positive (Lebesgue) measure. Show that $\sum_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

I define $E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: G(x)<\infty\}$ and $E_k=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: G(x)\leq k\}$. Then $E=\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}E_k$ which implies that there is $k'$ such $m(E_{k'})>0$. From this I obtain that
\begin{align*}
\int_{E_{k'}}G(x)\,dx=\sum_n|b_n|\int_{E_{k'}}|g(nx+a_n)|\,dx<k'm(E_{k'})
\end{align*}

This is as far I can go. I will appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $m(E_{k'})>0$, there is a measurable subset $F\subset E_{k'}$ such that $0<m(F)<\infty$. Let $c_n=\int_F|g(nx + b_n)|\,dx$ (each $c_n$ is finite since $g$ is bounded and $F$ is chosen to have finite measure).

From the bound in the OP,
$\sum_n|b_n c_n|<k\,m(F)<\infty$. The sequence $c_n$ is bounded below for all $n$ large enough since
$$c_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac1{T}\int^T_0 |g(x)|\,dx\Big)\,m(F)>0$$
This is [Fejer's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671), a result similar to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. The conclusion then follows by comparison.