# convergence of $\int_{-1}^1\sin(n\pi x)f(x)dx$ to $0$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I was playing around with this question in my graphic calculator and noticed, that $\int_{-1}^1\sin(n\pi x)f(x)dx\to0$ for $n\to\infty$, where $f\in L^p((-1,1))$ and $1<p<\infty$. While trying to proof this I had the idea of writing $\int_{-1}^1\sin(n\pi x)f(x)dx=\sum_{i=-n}^{n-1}\int_{i/n}^{(i+1)/n}\sin(n\pi x)f(x)dx$, hoping it would simplify the question, but I can't see how this could help.
Help proving or disproving this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Set up the Riemann sum and carefully choose your partition points so that it's always zero.

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't this just the famous fact that fourier coefficients go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (for well behaved enough functions)?

Comment: Yes @CharlesHudgins, but he probably does not know about that already so he must prove it

Comment: @JulesBesson I think I would be just as confused as Charles. It's very strange for someone to have a working knowledge of $L^p$ spaces before Fourier series.

Comment: This was the case for me haha

Comment: I do know about the Riemann-Lebesgue-Lemma if you mean that, but im not too familiar with, so should I just take the Fourier series of $\sin(n\pi x)f(x)$?

Comment: no, your integral is proportional to $b_n$ (the sine part)

Comment: @algebrah I think you are confusing the Fourier transform with Fourier series. Have you studied Fourier series?

Comment: I startet studying the Fourier series last week, but in a more abstract setting. I found how to calculate the the $b_k$'s on Wikipedia. Knowing about the Riemand-Lebesgue-Lemma, this should do it, thanks ^^

Comment: [That](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) is a well known behavior of intgegration with rapidly oscillating periodic functions.

Comment: Pretend $f$ is $C^1$ and integrate by parts. Then ….