# $\int _0^1 f(x)g_n (x) dx \rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, sequence-of-function

Question:

Prove $\int _0^1 f(x)g_n (x) dx \rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow 0$ for $f\in \mathcal{L}^1([0,1])$ and $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$ such that

(i) $|g_n(x)|\leq C$ a.e. $x\in [0,1]$ for some $C<\infty$, and

(ii) $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}\int _0^a g_n(x) dx=0$ for all $a\in [0,1]$.

My progress:

My first step is to show for $f = \phi$ a simple function, the above statement is true. Then by $f\in \mathcal{L}^1([0,1])$, there exists a simple function $\phi$ such that $\int _0^1 |f-\phi| dx < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon >0$. So $|\int _0^1 f(x)g_n (x) dx - \int _0^1 \phi(x)g_n (x) dx|\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow 0$.

But there is a question that cannot be avoided, which is I always need to show that $\int _E |f||g_n| dx \rightarrow 0 $ for $E$ measurable and $m(E)<\epsilon$. For this problem, let $F = \{x\in [0,1]: |g_n(x)| > C \}$ and $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}m(F) = 0$. Now $\int _E |f||g_n| dx = \int _{E\cap F} |f||g_n| dx + \int _{E\cap F^c} |f||g_n| dx \leq \int _{E\cap F} |f||g_n| dx + \int _{E\cap F^c} C |f|dx $. $\int _{E\cap F^c} C |f|dx $ is less than $\int _{E} C |f|dx $. But for $\int _{E\cap F} |f||g_n| dx$, I am not sure how to formally prove it is not arbitrarily large.

If you have any comments or other way to solve this problem, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding "the question that cannot be avoided" - you do not have to show that  $\int _E |g_n| dx \rightarrow 0$. In fact, this not true under your assumptions. You have to show that $\int _E |f||g_n| dx \rightarrow 0$ and this follows from the fact that integral of $f$ over a "small" set is "small" plus the fact that $g's$ are bounded.

Comment: @Mittens If $g_n (x) = cos(nx)$, then $\lim g_n (x)$ does not exist. I guess that is why I cannot use dominated convergence.

Comment: @Salcio I do need to prove $\int _E |f||g_n| dx \rightarrow 0$. This is also the part I'm confused because now $g$ is bounded a.e. and I don't know what to deal with $\int _{E\cap F} |f||g_n| dx$.

Comment: The subspace $C^1$ is dense in $L^1,$ it suffices to consider $C^1$ function $f$. Then the conclusion can be obtained by integration by parts.

Comment: @Thmyem: sorry, I misread your posting the first time. the key is to use the density of step functions on $L_1[0,1]$ and the boundedness of $g_n$. The density argument is  similar to the end of the proof of Fejer's theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671)

Comment: @Thmyem - Your solution is OK. Regarding your question, what you are missing (most likely) is the fact that if a function is integrable ( and $f$ is) then for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that for any set $|E| < \delta$ $\int _E |f dx < \epsilon$. Lastly, since $g_n$ are bounded similar estimation holds for $fg_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

It follows from the  assumption on $g_n$ that $\int^b_a g_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ for all $0\leq a<b\leq 1$ and so $\int^1_0 s g_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ fo any step function $s$.

Now, step functions, i.e. functions if the for $\sum^N_{k=1}a_k\mathbb{1}_{(\alpha_k,\beta_k]}$, are dense in $L_1([0,1])$.  Fix $f\in L_1[0,1]$, For any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a step function $s_\varepsilon$ on $[0,1]$ such that
$\|f-s_\varepsilon\|_1<\varepsilon$. Then
\begin{align}
\Big|\int^1_0 fg_n\Big|&\leq\Big|\int^1_0(f-s_\varepsilon)g_n\Big|  +\big|\int^1_0s_\varepsilon g_n\big|\\
&\leq C\|f-s_\varepsilon\|_1+\big|\int^1_0s_\varepsilon g_n\big|
\end{align}
Since $\lim_n\int^1_0s_\varepsilon g_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$,
$$\limsup_n\Big|\int^1_0 fg_n\Big|\leq C\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

By part (ii), it follows that for any simple functions of the form $\phi = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \chi_{[0, a_i]}$ where $a_i \in [0,1]$ satisfy the following limit
$$\lim_n \int_0^1 g_n \phi \, dx =0.$$
Let $\epsilon >0$ and $f \in L^1([0,1])$  be given. As every simple function defined on $[0,1]$ can be expressed as a linear combination of functions of the form $\chi_{[0,a]}$ where $a \in [0,1]$ and simple functions are dense in $L^1([0,1])$ there exists $\phi = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \chi_{[0, a_i]}$ so that $\int_0^1 |f - \phi| \, dx < \epsilon/C$.
So,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f g_n \, dx &= \int_0^1 (f - \phi) g_n \, dx + \int_0^1 \phi g_n \, dx\\
&\leq \int_0^1 |f - \phi| |g_n| \, dx + \int_0^1 \phi g_n \, dx\\
&\leq \epsilon + \int_0^1 \phi g_n \, dx
\end{align*}
Allowing $n \to \infty$ and as $\epsilon >0$ can be arbitrary small the result follows.